# Error in Sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I get the below error when I try to call a method from Https web service inside a web part. I am running WIN2k3, SP 2007.

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://xyz.local:8000/path_to_endpoint. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

The issue was the web service which was residing as Http. However, when the reference was made, web.config defined the web service using the httpstransport method.

Changed the `httpstransport` method to `httptransportmethod` and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable system.net tracing so we can see whats going on?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

Comment: Hi Trikks, just figured out the issue was the web service resides as Http and the web.config is using httpstransport method

Comment: @techguy, you should post the solution as a different answer and accept it.